# Why doesn't date.format() from Template::Plugin::Date return the duration I expect?

Tags: perl

I have a duration in seconds that I'm trying to convert to HH:MM:SS format with the Template Toolkit plugin [Template::Plugin::Date](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Plugin::Date):

```
[% Use date %]
[% SET tseconds = 478966 %]
[% date.format(tseconds ,'%H:%M:%S') %]
```

This returns 13:02:46, but I expected it to return 133:02:46 (478966 seconds is equal to 133 hours, 2 minutes, and 46 seconds). Is there any other way to convert a duration in seconds to HH:MM:SS format using Template Toolkit?

Comment: `date` works with timestamps (not duration), and it accurately provided the hour, minute and second components of the provided timestamp  (`1970-01-06T13:02:46Z`).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a plugin that will do that, but you can write your own function and pass it in the information hash, like this

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Time::Seconds;
use Template;


my $vars = {
    format_hms => \&format_hms,
};

my $tt = Template->new;

$tt->process(\<<END_TEMPLATE, $vars);
[% SET tseconds = 478966 %]
[% format_hms(tseconds) %]
END_TEMPLATE


sub format_hms {

    my $t = Time::Seconds->new(shift);

    my $h = int $t->hours;
    $t -= $h * ONE_HOUR;

    my $m = int $t->minutes;
    $t -= $m * ONE_MINUTE;

    my $s = int $t->seconds;

    sprintf "%d:%02d:%02d\n", $h, $m, $s;
}
```

#### output

```
133:02:46
```

---

#### Update

In case you would prefer to make the code available through a custom plugin instead of by passing a subroutine reference in the `%vars` hash, here is a simple module that will allow you to do that

```
package Custom::Template::Plugin::Duration;

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use base 'Template::Plugin';

use Time::Seconds;


sub format_hms {

    my $self = shift;

    my $t = Time::Seconds->new($_[0]);

    my $h = int $t->hours;
    $t -= $h * ONE_HOUR;

    my $m = int $t->minutes;
    $t -= $m * ONE_MINUTE;

    my $s = int $t->seconds;

    sprintf "%d:%02d:%02d\n", $h, $m, $s;
}

1;
```

If you save that as `Custom/Template/Plugin/Duration.pm` in one of the `@INC` directories (the current working directory is a good bet) then you can write code like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Template;

my $tt = Template->new(
    PLUGINS => {
        duration => 'Custom::Template::Plugin::Duration',
    }
);

$tt->process(\<<END_TEMPLATE);
[% USE duration %]
[% SET tseconds = 478966 %]
[% tseconds %] is equivalent to
[% duration.format_hms(tseconds) %]
END_TEMPLATE
```

#### output

```
478966 is equivalent to
133:02:46
```

However there is nothing essentially different here except from the way the template is given access to the subroutine. The underlying code is identical

Comment: Thanks for the update but I am looking this to do done in .html file in [% ----- %] tag . Also [% date.format(tsecond,'%H:%M:%S') %] , is working fine for below 24 hours , I also tested this as [% date.format(tsecond,'%I:%M:%S') %]  in state of %H it is %I ----> for 24 hours , but it is not doing any calculation and result is not correct

Comment: @sailasahoo: I don't understand your question. I have shown you how to use Template Toolkit markup to insert the value you want, and I have explained that there is no module that will format the hours as you want. The only way is to write your own function, and a convenient way to use it is to pass it in the **vars** hash.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the respond . I understood the code you have written and the script you have written . But I need to do this in HTML . If data.format is not working , then I will script to javascript to do this . In Perl , we can in different ways like localtime , posix,GMTime etc . but I was looking in TT in HTML .  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still unclear what you're doing. HTML isn't an executable language and you can't call the Template Toolkit processor from JavaScript. Do you mean you are running `tpage` perhaps? If you can't do things this way then it would be simple to write a small Template Toolkit plugin of your own that does do what you want.

Comment: Hi, it's very simple , I am calling my client side script (html) from server side script (perl)  using template toolkit . I hope you are not sure how I am using this framework. anyway , From the HTML page I can use [% %] and can use [% USE date %] .   I have to do some calculation on HTML and format the seconds to H:M:S  that' s all .

Comment: @sailasahoo: Okay, you're doing exactly what I imagined; it's just your terminology that confused me. First of all, there is no client-side script and you cannot "call" HTML -- it is simply data. Your Perl code must create a `Template::Toolkit` object and call something like `$tt->process` to process the template file, just as the code in my solution does. Template files contain (in this case) HTML data as well as directives that build text dynamically when the Perl code calls `process`. They normally have a suffix of `.tt` and are not HTML files.

Comment: @sailasahoo: You can use my solution above if you define the subroutine in your Perl code and pass it to the template through the `%vars` hash in the `process` call. Think of my code above as corresponding to your own Perl code, and the two lines of template code as being equivalent to your template file. I copied it from your own question thinking that you would understand the correspondence.

Comment: @sailasahoo: I have added a simple plugin solution so that you can provide the subroutine that way if you prefer.